# Get a list of all QObjects created in a Application

Tags: qt, qwidget, qobject

To get a list of all the QWidgets created in an application we can simply call `QApplication::allWidgets()`.

I've read the documentation, and I haven't found anything like this to get a list of all QObjects.  If an application creates stand-alone QObjects that are not QWidgets I have no such function to use.

Is there a method to obtain such a list?

Answer (score 11):

To begin with it's important to understand the difference between the `QObject` and `QWidget` classes.

#### class QObject

QObject instances have a pointer to their parent which may or may not be a null pointer. It's quite legitimate to create a QObject instance without a parent so long as you understand that it is your responsibility for that instance's lifetime i.e. if you don't `delete` it you will leak memory.

#### class QWidget

Although it appears you can create a QWidget without a parent, you can't. When you create an instance of a QWidget "without a parent" (i.e. by supplying a null pointer or letting it default to a null pointer) it's parent effectively gets set to your application's QApplication<sup>1</sup> instance.

> Is there a method to obtain such a list?

No. The reason `QApplication::allWidgets()` works is due to the fact that all QWidget instances have a pointer to them which is stored in your single QApplication instance. There is no central store of QObject pointers and therefore no in-built way of retrieving them.

One way around this is to ensure **yourself** that all QObjects instances (or instances of classes which inherit QObject) have a valid parent.  Then you can use the QObject functions [children()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#children), [findChild()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#findChild) and [findChildren()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#findChildren) to get pointers to these objects.

These are powerful tools, and like anything powerful, **use them with care**!  Make sure you understand C++ object life spans before you use these in production code.

---

#### Notes:

1. `QApplication` inherits from `QCoreApplication` which inherits from `QObject`. There are [some restrictions](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qapplication.html#QApplication) placed on how QApplication is used by the Qt framework.