# Broadcast a Qt signal to every object's instances

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I'm searching for a way to have a kind of signal broadcast with Qt.
In my design I got an `Auth` object that can be used inside c++ and qml side:

```
class Auth : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Auth() ;

    Q_INVOKABLE bool isLogged() const ;

    Q_INVOKABLE void reconnect() ;

    Q_INVOKABLE void login(QString mail, QString password) ;

    Q_INVOKABLE void logout() ;

protected:
    static QString token_ ;

signals:
    void error(QString message) ;
    void logged() ;
    void loggedOut() ;
};
```

When `login` is called then `logged()` signal is fired and `loggedOut()` signal for `logout()`.

1- In the qml part i've got this code:

```
Auth {
    id: auth
    onError: console.log("auth error")
    onLogged: console.log("auth logged")
    onLoggedOut: console.log("auth logged out")
}
```

2- And in the c++ side I may do in some failure cases:

```
Auth auth ;
auth.logout() ;
```

The two `Auth` objects from 1 and 2 are not the same so the `loggedOut` emitted from one is not fired in the other, that's ok.

Now what I'm trying to do is to have a way to broadcast the `loggedOut` signal to every instances of `Auth`. I'd like to avoid to share a common instance of `Auth` between C++ and qml side.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, since you're essentially looking for a Qt/C++ way of finding all instances of a particular class (`Auth`, in this case).  See e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340988/get-a-list-of-all-qobjects-created-in-a-application) or [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/50739/solved-get-all-objects-with-same-class/2).

Depending on lots of other factors, you could:

- maintain a static list of all class instances within the `Auth` object and connect the different instances within `Auth::Auth()`
- manually connect `Auth::loggedOut()` for the first `Auth` object to all other instances (note: be careful, if you get a circular connection you'll enter an infinite loop).
- make `Auth` a singleton (though I'd consider that violating your "don't share an instance" stipulation)

There are probably other (maybe better) options too.

Comment: I implemented the first method. I was thinking to switch to the second but they are not strictly equivalent, it seems I would lose the ability to trigger an event to a peculiar instance.